# Как избавиться от выдачи prompt в bat-скрипте после активации вирт.окружении и продолжить выполнение скрипта?

Tags: python, windows

У меня проблема с запуском тестов в вирт.окружении python35 созданного с помощью модуля `venv` из стандартной библиотеки `python`-a.

Есть скрипт `test.cmd`, вот его содержимое:

```
@.\\pyenv\\Scripts\\activate.bat
@python manage test
```

Dот результат его выполнения в `cmd.exe`:

```
d:\personal\projects\python-workspace\myproject>test.cmd
(pyenv) d:\personal\projects\python-workspace\myproject>
```

Другими словами вторая команда в `test.cmd` не выполняется, а выдается prompt.

Как избежать его выдачи и продолжить выполнение `test.cmd`?